# Generate sequence number using Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a problem where I need to generate sequence number starting from 1 in the whole file.

For ex lets say I have a **BIG** file as follows:-

abc,123
abb,111
ccc,122
.....N number of such line

Now my output should be as follows:-

1,abc,123
2,abb,111
3,ccc,122
....so on.

The problem of doing this using mapreduce is that every split of the file is processed in parallel by different map function due to which the sequence could not be maintained. Please don't tell me to use single reducer to do this. I don't want to use single reducer as I want to do this in parallel using typical mapreduce job. So is there any best way so that this could be done using map-reduce?

Comment: See this should be useful : http://blog.data-miners.com/2009/11/hadoop-and-mapreduce-parallel-program.html

Comment: Do you need to maintain order?

Comment: Yes, I need the order to be maintained

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but its slightly tricky. You need to work with the "mapred_job_id" environment variable which gives you the job ID of the reducer.

For example, when you read in the "mapred_job_id" variable, you may get something like this: "job_201302272236_0001". You can take the last part of that job ID, which is "0001".

Using this, you can construct a prefix for each of the lines output by the reducer. For example, if you know that each reducer outputs a maximum of 1000 lines, you can have the output of this reducer be 1000-1999. The second reducer would have a job ID "job_201302272236_0002", so it would take 2000-2999.

Sample code for the above algorithm using Python (Hadoop streaming):

```
import os, sys
jobID = os.environ['mapred_job_id']
reducerID = jobID.split("_")[-1]

count = 0
for line in sys.stdin: 
  print str((reducerID*NUM)+count) + "," + line
  count += 1
```